# Joint probability and dependent variables

Tags: probability

I ran into this in the exercise section in my textbook and I'm not sure how to proceed:

$f(x,y) = 2$

for $0 \leq x \leq 1, 0 \leq y \leq 1, 0 \leq x + y \leq 1$, and 0 elsewhere.

Find $P(X \leq 3/4, Y \leq 3/4)$

I thought it would make sense to set the upper bound of x to 1-y and integrate from $0 \to 3/4$ and $0 \to 1-y$, but the answer doesn't seem to be right.

Could someone provide some guidance?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you draw a picture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conditions of the problem define a region in the x-y plane where the problem is defined. Using the three inequalities, we have the triangular region from (0,0) to (1,0) to (0,1) to (0,0). The area of this region is $\frac{1*1}{2} = \frac{1}{2}$. The density over this region is uniformly 2, so we confirm that the overall density sums to 1.

To find the probability where $P(X \le \frac{3}{4}, Y \le \frac{3}{4})$. The easiest way to do this is geometrically shading where it is true over this reigon and where its not true.

Answer (score 0):

The probability is
$$
\int_0^{3/4} dx \int_0^{\min(3/4, 1-x)} f(x,y) dy
$$

to satisfy both constrains
$$
Y\le 3/4
\\
Y\le 1-X
$$
Can you proceed further?

Answer (score 0):

Plot the joint density function. 
Mark the region for which joint density is valid according to the given constraints.

Then Shade the region whose volume (probability) you want to calculate.

You've don't even need to use calculus since joint density is uniform.